# DBSCAN noise points

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, dbscan

I'm working on an algorithm that matches people based on geographical distance and for this, I'm using the DBSCAN algorithm.

This is the output I get after running my code

```
db_e= dbscan::dbscan(eng2_scaled, eps= 0.5, minPts= 3)


DBSCAN clustering for 10 objects.
Parameters: eps = 0.5, minPts = 3
The clustering contains 1 cluster(s) and 7 noise points.

0 1 
7 3 

Available fields: cluster, eps, minPts
```

Is there a way where I can force the noise points (in this algorithm, individuals who live further away) into my clusters, without relying on manually placing them in a cluster?

This is the code I'm working with

```
               id       long         lat
 [1,] -1.08661792  0.6479382  0.29786292
 [2,] -0.92913706  0.6606378  0.27583940
 [3,] -0.77165620 -0.0262808  0.01227102
 [4,] -0.61417534  0.6804854  0.17569930
 [5,] -0.45669449  0.7748932 -1.45946459
 [6,] -0.14173277 -2.3581307  0.07462387
 [7,]  0.01574809 -0.5405659 -0.84936268
 [8,]  0.80315237  0.5367247 -1.25770012
 [9,]  1.43307580  0.4708911  0.80020084
[10,]  1.74803752 -0.8465929  1.93003003
```

Comment: Have you tried using a larger value for `eps`?

Comment: Hi , yes I have but it doesn't take care of the noise points and instead, the cluster size (despite minpts being 3) increases....

Comment: In the output that you show, there is only one cluster (with three points) and all the rest of the points are noise points.  How can the cluster size increase without some of the noise points going into the cluster?

Comment: Hm so if I increase the eps, say from a 0.5 (which is what it is above) to 1 (with k=3 constant) - there will still be only 1 cluster, with 4 points (not 3) and 6 noise points.

Comment: But what I want, is to see if there is a way to increase the number of clusters and distribute those noise points across those clusters.

Comment: you could try  `minPts=2`

Comment: Having the same problem!

Comment: Can you provide your data so that we can see how to adjust?

Comment: Yes, thank you - edited my answer to include that!

Comment: Are you including id in your clustering - or only lat-long?

Comment: All 3! ~ i'm trying to cluster based on location

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is get an idea if there should be more clusters, so let's look at a basic plot of your data.

```
plot(eng2_scaled[,2:3])
```

[image: Basic plot]

It is easy to see why 3 points (at the center right) clustered, but nothing else. You could imagine that the two points at the lower right belong together. In order to get that, you must drop minPts to 2.

```
library(dbscan)
db_e = dbscan(eng2_scaled[,2:3], eps= 0.5, minPts= 2)
plot(eng2_scaled[,2:3], pch=20, col=db_e$cluster+1)
```

[image: Points colored by cluster]

Beyond this,  it is hard to see why any of these points should be in a cluster. But there are only 10 points.  Why not just group them by hand?

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! For now, manual is something that I am doing but, I'm going to be running this algorithm to a larger participant set (N= 1000) ~ so, there will be situations where participants who stay a little further away will be categorized as 'Noise', so I was trying to format my code in such a way that... I reduce the amount of manual matching I do (just for convenience sake)